# Pretty-print a std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

How can I pretty-print a `std::vector`? For example, if I construct a `std::vector<int>(6, 1)`, what can I run it through to get output like `{1 1 1 1 1 1}` in C++? It needs to be generic as the size and value might change, so `std::vector<int>(4, 0)` would be `{0 0 0 0}`.

Comment: what do you mean? you would like to just print the elements in the vector to a particular formatting?

Comment: use a stream to print them?

Comment: Display in console screen? Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Yes print the elements in a particular formatting in console screen. I just need an idea how to go about doing it , i can possibly build the code myself

Comment: I'll look into the possible duplicate answer. Apologies for the duplication.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, std::vector<T> vec)
{
    os<<"{ ";
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, " "));
    os<<"}";
    return os;
}
```

then you can output your vectors with the normal `operator<<` syntax:

```
std::cout<<yourVector;
```

you can see this in action [here](http://ideone.com/IOCsKq).

But for more flexible solutions have a look at the [question linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).

---

Edit: if you don't want the two spaces (at the beginning and at the end):

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, std::vector<T> vec)
{
    os<<"{";
    if(vec.size()!=0)
    {
        std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end()-1, std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, " "));
        os<<vec.back();
    }
    os<<"}";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not produce the output the OP requested, because it will have a trailing separator: `{0 0 0 0 }` (if that matters).

Comment: Probably a typo/missed by C&P'ing, but if you template your operator for arbitrary `T`, you don't want `ostream_iterator<int>`.

Comment: @us2012: correct, fixed.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: you are right, for some reason I always think that `ostream_iterator` takes care of that. Well, I'll just add a space at the start to make it symmetrical. :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: It's the reason why I only use this with whitespace or newline as separator, because it is practically useless for anything else. On the other hand, you add a check if the vector is not empty, and then just copy until `--vec.end()` and print the last item in an extra step.

Comment: I have a problem that sometimes the value std::vector<int>(4,0) is stored in a string, for some reason.  like str = "std::vector<int>(4,0)" and is displayed in the database as it is. But I would like to display it as {0 0 0 0} Is it possible to do some type conversion for these cases ??

Comment: @user2029504: you can't evaluate that kind of expression at runtime in C++; if you really need such a thing, you could write some kind of ad-hoc parser, but the best solution is just to store the vector in some fixed, easily parsable format (like the one we are talking about here).

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
string str = "std::vector<int>(6,0)" ;
 
unsigned found = str.find('(');
char c = str[found+1];
int i = c - '0'; 
char ch = str[found+3];
int j = ch - '0';
 
str = "{ ";
for(int k = 0; k < i ; k++)
{
str = str + ch + " " ;
}
str = str + " }";
 
cout << str << endl; 
 
return 0;
}

Comment: This does the work but does not look very nice. Also, how do I post it here so that its more readable. Sorry

Comment: @user2029504: create another question for this new problem.

Comment: Works with back() instead of last(). I've already suggested the edit.

Comment: @hsandt: thank you, approved!